# ANTLR4 parser generation: issue with simple grammar for conditional expressions

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am trying to generate a lexer and parser for a simple language. At the moment, the language can only parse a conditional expression. A conditional expression is much like one in C, and because I am only learning the rudiments here, all the gotchas we have in a language like C I am not going to be concerned about implementing.

I have the following grammar:

```
grammar Simple ;

cond_expr     : left_paren operand operator operand right_paren ;
operand       : function_expr | ID | literal | cond_expr ;
function_expr : ID left_paren paramList right_paren ;
paramList     : param (',' param)* ;
param         : ID | function_expr ;
literal       : string | number ;
string        : '"' sentence '"' ;
sentence      : (WORD | WORD (' ' WORD)*)* ;
number        : INTEGER | FLOAT ;
left_paren    : LEFT_PAREN ;
right_paren   : RIGHT_PAREN ;
operator      : OPERATOR ;

INTEGER     : [0-9]+ ;
FLOAT       : INTEGER '.' INTEGER | '.' INTEGER ;
LEFT_PAREN  : '(' ;
RIGHT_PAREN : ')' ;
ID          : [A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]* ;
WORD        : [A-Za-z]+ ;
OPERATOR    : ('==' | '>=' | '<=' | '!=' | '&&' | '||' | '~') ;
WS          : (' '|'\r'|'\n'|'\t') -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

And when I run the parser on it, I am not getting the results I expect. Here's an example of an incorrect output:

```sh
~/sandbox $ grun Simple cond_expr -tree
(a (c, d (e, f)) != b)
line 1:2 mismatched input ' ' expecting OPERATOR
line 1:5 mismatched input ',' expecting OPERATOR
line 1:8 mismatched input ' ' expecting ')'
(cond_expr (left_paren () (operand a) (operator  ) (operand (cond_expr (left_paren () (operand c) (operator ,  ) (operand d) (right_paren   ( e ,   f))) (right_paren )))
```

What is the mistake in my grammar? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `WS` rule is incomplete.

Comment: Please don't use JS snippet wrappers for your code when you in fact have no JS code here.

Comment: @GRosenberg: Sorry about it, the WS rule was incomplete as a typo, I have corrected it now.

Comment: @MikeLischke: Sorry, and thanks for correcting!

Comment: To me, it looks like your test input just doesn't conform to your grammar - `a` should be followed by an operator.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I agree. I realized a number of mistakes after I posted this, and I still believe it might help somebody, so I left it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears that the grammar is a direct implementation of an EBNF representation of the desired DSL.  A bit more work is required to get it to work well in ANTLR. As is:

1) there is a mutual left recursion problem with the rules `function_expr`, `paramList`, and `param`;

2) `sentence` can match nothing;

3) `WS` is hidden in the lexer, so `sentence` could never match, anyway ;);

4) the `ID` rule shadows `WORD`, so `WORD` tokens will never be emitted.

(You should have received a Tool warning on 1 and 2; never ignore, since warnings indicate that run-time behavior *can* be affected.)

The basic form for an expression rule is to list, in a single rule, all of the alternate forms of the expression.

```
expr  : LPAREN expr RPAREN 
      | expr operator expr
      | function
      | string
      | number
      | ID
      ;

function  : ID LPAREN ( ID | function ) (',' ( ID | function ))* RPAREN ;

string        : STRING ;
number        : INTEGER | FLOAT ;
operator      : OPERATOR ;

STRING : '"' .*? '"' ;
```

(untested)

So `(a (c, d (e, f)) != b)` should correctly evaluate to

```
expr (function ( ID, function ( ID, ID ) ) operator ID
```

Comment: thank you, and apologies for my tardy response. I got caught up in improving my grammar and then saw yours and began incorporating elements of yours into my grammar. In the end, your ideas work for me (though my understanding of this is still in progress), so I am going to accept it. Just one small comment: `function` is a reserved keyword in many languages (my target, JS, being one of them) and so you are better served with a different parser name. I went with `function_expression`. Simple fix. Thank you!